# Theme attributes in pre-lollipop Drawable using DrawableCompat?

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I've successfully used theme attributes (ex. `?attr/colorPrimary`) within a `VectorDrawable` loaded through `VectorDrawableCompat`.  Is there a way to do the same with a simple `Drawable` containing a shape via `DrawableCompat`?